# C Dynamic Array; Can't Delete

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic

Really stuck on the following problem. I'm creating a dynamic array, but when I re-size (for which the logic is creating a new array, copying the values of the old array into the new array, and then deleting old array). I keep getting a memory error when trying to free the memory of old array. See below; I feel like it's something obvious but my eyes just can't see it right now.

Struct to hold the array:

```
struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
    int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
    int capacity;   /* capacity ofthe array */
};
```

Function to create a new array:

```
 DynArr *newDynArr(int cap)
{
    assert(cap > 0);
    DynArr *r = (DynArr *)malloc(sizeof(DynArr));

    assert(r != 0);
    initDynArr(r, cap);
    return r;
}
```

Initializing the array:

```
void initDynArr(DynArr *v, int capacity)
{
    assert(capacity > 0);
    assert(v != 0);
    v->data = (TYPE *)malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * capacity);
    assert(v->data != 0);
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = capacity;
}
```

Function to resize the array:

```
void _dynArrSetCapacity(DynArr *v, int newCap)
{   


    struct DynArr *newData;

    /*new array to hold new values*/
    newData = newDynArr(newCap);

    ///*Intialize the new array*/
    initDynArr(newData,newCap);

    /*Copy values from old array into new array*/
    for (int a = 0; a < v->size; a++)
    {
        addDynArr(newData, v->data[a]);
    }

    /*Free the old array, data and array, Cant get this to work*/
    /*freeDynArr(v) */


    /*Have v point to new array*/
    v = newData;
}
```

And function to free the memory, which is throwing me the error:

```
void freeDynArr(DynArr *v)
{

    if (v->data!= 0)
    {
        free(v->data);  /* free the space on the heap */
        v->data = 0;    /* make it point to null */
    }
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: `_dynArrSetCapacity` shouldn't allocate a new DynArr (the caller still wants to have the same pointer).  It should malloc a new array of type TYPE, copy `v->data` into it, free `v->data` and replace `v->data` with the newly allocated one

Comment: Also, when you really want to do a free (of the data and the meta-data structure), `freeDynArr`needs to free both v->data and `v` itself.

Comment: allocating a new array type did do the trick. But we should be able to accomplish the same with allocating an entirely new struct right?

Comment: No.  After calling _dynArrSetCapacity, the caller is left holding a pointer to the freed structure.  Accessing it will cause either a crash or a hard to track bug.

Comment: There is a C function called realloc that helps you free the previous data and allocate a new one with the old one's value, which fundamentally resize the data.

Comment: Modification of argument in a function does not apply to the caller's variable. Instead, you should use `memcpy`

Answer (score 0):

Your `_dynArrSetCapacity` function sets up another `DynArr` block by allocating it again using `malloc`. The problem here is that you neither return the `newData` array nor keep the old array (`v`).

This causes a problem on the caller side. You could've checked your code by doing a `while(TRUE)` type of block, before exiting `_dynArrSetCapacity`, which should show that your code doesn't crash before returning.

You have two solutions:

**i) Return `newData` to the caller:** While calling `_dynArrSetCapacity`, your code should update the `DynArr` variable being used, something like the following:

`DynArr *updatedData = _dynArrSetCapacity(newData, newCapacity);`

**i) Pass a double pointer to `_dynArrSetCapacity`:** The other way is to allow `_dynArrSetCapacity` to automatically update the pointer to the old `DynArr` struct. This would require the caller to pass a pointer to that pointer (resulting a double pointer of course). This is called passing `out` parameters sometimes.

`void _dynArrSetCapacity(DynArr** oldData, int newCapacity);`

```
{
        DynArr *orgBuffer;// Our new dynamic array to hold the original
                          // buffer of data

        .... Code that will initialize the buffer, do something cool....

        _dynArrSetCapacity(&orgBuffer, NEW_CAPACITY);

}
```

---

The error you did while coding is that at the end of `_dynArrSetCapacity` you wrote `v = newData` and thought that it will be updated for the caller. That is wrong totally. That is because `v` is copied in the stack and then passed to the callee, which means any changes to `v` will not affect the originally passed argument (in code).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the realloation yourself, you can use a function called `realloc` that help you resize an malloc'd array, so the implementation is simpler.

```
void _dynArrSetCapacity(DynArr *v, int newCap)
{
    if(v==NULL||v->data==NULL){
        return; // Return early if they are NULL
    }
    /* Resize the data to newcap*sizeof(TYPE) bytes */
    TYPE* tmp=(TYPE*)realloc(v->data,newCap*sizeof(TYPE));
    if(tmp!=NULL){
        v->data=tmp;
    }
}
```